# 'this' referring to something inside function instead of the object (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, loops, this

I have the following class:

```js
function courseOversight() {
  this.courseBlocks = []; // Stores the courseblocks on the page
  this.getCourseBlocks = function() {
    $(".course-block").each(function(){
      var block = new courseBlock();
      this.courseBlocks.push(block);
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to fill in the object's courseBlocks array with the courseBlocks on the page. However, in the each() loop, 'this' refers to the course-block I'm currently adding, and not to the courseOversight object. How would I access the courseOversights courseBlocks array without using the now unavailable 'this' keyword? Thanks!

Comment: I just realized I could make it work by constructing a local courseBlocks array in the getcourseBlocks function and then set the courseOversight's courseBlocks to that array. Is that the 'correct' way of doing it?

Comment: If any answer resolves your issue, please accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by assigning 'this' to a variable before you enter the each like the following

```
function courseOversight() {
var _this = this; //Assign 'this' context to a new var
this.courseBlocks = []; // Stores the courseblocks on the page
this.getCourseBlocks = function() {
    $(".course-block").each(function(){
        var block = new courseBlock();
        // Now you can call the following like this.
        // _this.courseBlocks.push(block);
        this.courseBlocks.push(block);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may save `this` to another variable (p.e. `self`)

```js
function courseBlock(){
}

function courseOversight() {
  var self = this;
  self.courseBlocks = []; // Stores the courseblocks on the page
  self.getCourseBlocks = function() {
    $(".course-block").each(function(){
      var block = new courseBlock();
      self.courseBlocks.push(block);
    });
  }
  self.getCourseBlocks();
  console.log("Tests: ", self.courseBlocks);
}
courseOversight();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="course-block">Block 1</div>
  <div class="course-block">Block 2</div>
  <div class="course-block">Block 3</div>
</div>
```